# How to animate balls with varying speeds in Tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tk-toolkit

```
import time, random
from tkinter import *

class Box( Frame ):

   def __init__( self ):      # __init__ runs when Box() executes     
      Frame.__init__( self )  # Frame is the top level component
      self.pack() 
      self.master.title( "Canvas animation" ) 
      self.master.geometry( "400x400" ) # size in pixels
      label = Label(self, text="    Bubbles    ")
      label.grid(row=1, column=1)
      # create Canvas component
      self.myCanvas = Canvas( self ) 
      self.myCanvas.grid(row=2, column=1)
      self.myCanvas.config(bg = 'cyan', height = 350, width = 350)

      self.balls = [] #list of balls belongs to the Box 

      self.paint()

      self.animate()

   def paint( self ):

      #create a list of balls
      for i in range(35):

      x1, y1 = random.randint(35,315), random.randint(35,315)
      x2, y2 = x1 + 30 , y1 + 30 #size


      ballObjectId = self.myCanvas.create_oval\
                     ( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = '')
      self.balls.append([ballObjectId, x1, y1])

  self.myCanvas.update()   
  print ("paint done")

   def animate( self ):
      #animate the list of balls
      for i in range(1000):
          for i in range(len(self.balls)):

          self.myCanvas.delete(self.balls[i][0])   #delete and redraw to move
          self.balls[i][1] += random.randint(-2,2) #change coordinates
          self.balls[i][2] += random.randint(-10,0)
          x1, y1 = self.balls[i][1], self.balls[i][2]
          x2, y2 = x1 + random.randint(30,31) , y1 + random.randint(30,31)

          self.balls[i][0]=(self.myCanvas.create_oval\
                        ( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = ''))
          self.myCanvas.update()   


def main():
   Box().mainloop() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

This is the code I have so far. The problem I can't seem to solve is I need the balls to move a different speeds and also have different sizes. The final step I need to do is have the balls go to the top and come back up from the bottom. So the final product should be balls of multiple sizes traveling at different speeds to the top of the canvas then appearing back at the bottom. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have wrong indentation in `paint()` and `animate()` methods. Your `for` cycles do nothing at all. Just indent by one tab all the code you want to have in your `for` cycles under your `for`s.

Comment: The `for` loops won't just do nothing; the program won't compile with indentation errors. It's probably from pasting the code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a custom class that represents one ball. Have the code to move the ball be inside that class. Each ball can then have its own velocity and direction.

Here's a really simple example for a ball that falls. You would need to add logic for bouncing, falling in different directions, etc.

```
class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, canvas, x=10, y=10, radius=10, color="red", speed=1):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.speed = speed
        self.canvas_id = canvas.create_oval(x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius,
                                            outline=color, fill=color)
    def move(self, on=True):
        self.canvas.move(self.canvas_id, self.speed, self.speed)
```

You would use this with something like this:

```
self.canvas = Canvas(...)
self.balls = []
for i in range(10):
    <compute x, y, color, speed, ...>
    ball = Ball(self.canvas, x, y, radius, color, speed)
    self.balls.append(ball)
```

To animate them, set up a simple loop:

```
def animate(self):
    for ball in self.balls:
        ball.move()
    self.canvas.after(30, self.animate)
```