# Trying to find a way to delay repeat cycle in a loop in Tkinter's Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

essentially, what I'm trying to do is move a ball across the screen, but like, small movements every few milliseconds, but tkinter takes the loop, adds all the milliseconds together and moves the ball where is should be (i.e, 250ms delay in a for loop for 4 increments, the ball moves after 1 whole second)

example code:

```
import tkinter *
root = Tk()

global x
global y
w = 200
h = 200
x = w/2
y = h/2

pic = Canvas(root,width=w,height=h)
pic.pack()

mover = pic.create_oval(x,y, x+10,y+10,fill="red")

def left(event):
    global x
    for num in range(4):
        x = -5
        y = 0
        pic.move(mover,x,y)
        root.after(250)

root.bind("<Left>",left)
```

what should be happening is 4 movements in 250ms intervals, however, it makes one large movement after a single second.

time.sleep() also causes the same error, globalizing y had no effect either(as expected)

I couldn't find another already answered question, so any help would appreciates, please and thanks!

Comment: There are many questions on this site related to moving an object on a canvas. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987967/7432) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36200248/7432) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+move+ball+canvas+)

Comment: use `after` without `for`-loop because `after` will repeate it.

Comment: All GUIs to works smoother don't update window directly when you change item but after endinng your function - this way it has to update window only once and it works smoother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All GUIs to work smoother they don't update/readraw window directly when you change item but after ending your function. This way it has to update window only once (when you make many changes in function) and it works smoother (it is less bliting).

---

If you want to use `after()` to repeate move then you need `after(250, left)` but you don't need `for`-loop

`after()` will send information `250, left` to `mainloop()` and it will execute `left()` after 250ms - and later you end your function so `mainloop()` may update window after one move.

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def left(event):
    move(-5, 0, 4)
    
def right(event):
    move(5, 0, 4)

def up(event):
    move(0, -5, 4)

def down(event):
    move(0, 5, 4)

def move(dx, dy, n):    
    pic.move(mover, dx, dy)

    n -= 1

    if n > 0:
        # repeate it again after 50ms
        root.after(50, move, dx, dy, n)
    
    # end of function so it goes back to mainloop and it can update/redraw window
        
# --- main ---

w = 200
h = 200
x = w/2
y = h/2

root = tk.Tk()

pic = tk.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)  # PEP8: spaces after `,`
pic.pack()

mover = pic.create_oval(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill="red")  # PEP8: spaces after `,`

root.bind("<Left>", left)  # PEP8: spaces after `,`
root.bind("<Right>", right)
root.bind("<Up>", up)
root.bind("<Down>", down)

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you use `after(250)` or `time.sleep(0.25)` to sleep then you need `root.update()` to force `mainloop()` to update/redraw window.

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def left(event):
    move(-5, 0, 4)
    
def right(event):
    move(5, 0, 4)

def up(event):
    move(0, -5, 4)

def down(event):
    move(0, 5, 4)

def move(dx, dy, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        pic.move(mover, dx, dy)

        root.update()   # <-- force `mainloop()` to update window

        root.after(50)
        #time.sleep(0.25)
        
# --- main ---

w = 200
h = 200
x = w/2
y = h/2

root = tk.Tk()

pic = tk.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)  # PEP8: spaces after `,`
pic.pack()

mover = pic.create_oval(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill="red")  # PEP8: spaces after `,`

root.bind("<Left>", left)  # PEP8: spaces after `,`
root.bind("<Right>", right)
root.bind("<Up>", up)
root.bind("<Down>", down)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** Both versions have one problem - when you press many keys then it will run move for all keys at the same time so it may move in strange way. It would need variable `is_moving = True/False` to control if it can move for other keys.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but just for clarification, the idea is, for smoothing purposes, canvas redraws after a loop completes, unless told specifically otherwise?